# vector data-pair element annihilation

Tags: r

**Example 1:**

Say I have a `input1` vector:

```
input1 <- c("A","A","X","B","Y")
```

my desired output:

```
"A"
```

where for every one `"X"` will eliminate every one `"A"` **closest** to it in the vector direction from right to left, likewise, `"Y"` eliminating `"B"`.

**Example 2:**

```
input2 <- c("A","A","B","X","B","B","Y","A","B","B","B","X","X")
```

my desired output would be:

```
"B","B","B","B","B"
```

My idea was using `which` and `match` to find the index position but I'm not sure how to proceed then

```
#find "A" position:
which(match(c("A","A","X","B","Y"), "A") %in% 1)

#find "B" position:
which(match(c("A","A","X","B","Y"), "B") %in% 1)

#find "X" position:
which(match(c("A","A","X","B","Y"), "X") %in% 1)

#find "Y" position:
which(match(c("A","A","X","B","Y"), "Y") %in% 1)
```

how would i approach problem with long vector such as example 2 above with random sequence of `"A"` `"B"` `"X"` and `"Y"` in-between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you are looking for. It works backwards through the string, setting each X/Y and the nearest A/B to `NA`, then removes all the `NA`s...

```
input <- c("A","A","B","X","B","B","Y","A","B","B","B","X","X")

annihilate <- function(x){
  for(i in rev(seq_along(x))){
    if(is.na(x[i])) next
    if(x[i]=="X") {
      x[i] <- NA
      x[tail(which(x[1:i]=="A"), 1)] <- NA
    } else if(x[i]=="Y") {
      x[i] <- NA
      x[tail(which(x[1:i]=="B"), 1)] <- NA
    } 
  }
  return(x[!is.na(x)])
}

annihilate(input)
[1] "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"
```